# Does a greedy approach work here?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, greedy

Suppose there are N groups of people and M tables. We know the size of each group and the capacity of each table. How do we match the people to the tables such that no two persons of the same group sit at the same table?

Does a greedy approach work for this problem ? (The greedy approach works as follows: for each table try to "fill" it with people from different groups).

Comment: No, at least not without further checks.  Consider two tables (capacity 1 and 2) and two groups (size 1 and 2).  If you first try to fill the first table, you might pick the loner, leaving the two members from the second group to sit together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathias:

> I suspect the following greedy approach works: starting with the largest group, take each group and allocate one person of that group per table, picking first tables with the most free seats.

Indeed. And a small variation of tkleczek's argument proves it.

Suppose there is a solution. We have to prove that the algorithm finds a solution in this case.

This is vacuously true if the number of groups is 0.

For the induction step, we have to show that if there is any solution, there is one where one member of the largest group sits at each of the (size of largest group) largest tables.

Condition L: For all pairs (T1,T2) of tables, if T1 < T2 and a member of the largest group sits at T1, then another member of the largest group sits at T2.

Let S1 be a solution. If S1 fulfills L we're done. Otherwise there is a pair (T1,T2) of tables with T1 < T2 such that a member of the largest group sits at T1 but no member of the largest group sits at T2.
Since T2 > T1, there is a group which has a member sitting at T2, but none at T1 (or there is a free place at T2). So these two can swap seats (or the member of the largest group can move to the free place at T2) and we obtain a solution S2 with fewer pairs of tables violating L. Since there's only a finite number of tables, after finitely many steps we have found a solution Sk satisfying L.

Induction hypothesis: For all constellations of N groups and all numbers M of tables, if there is a solution, the algorithm will find a solution.

Now consider a constellation of (N+1) groups and M tables where a solution exists. By the above, there is also a solution where the members of the largest group are placed according to the algorithm. Place them so. This reduces the problem to a solvable constellation of N groups and M' tables, which is solved by the algorithm per the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the groups and tables can be of unequal size, I don't think the greedy approach as described works (at least not without additional specifications). Suppose you have a table of 2 T1 and a table of 3 T2, and 3 groups {A1}, {B1,B2} and {C1,C2}. If I follow your algorithm, T1 will receive {A1,B1} and now you are left with T2 and {B2,C1,C2} which doesn't work. Yet there is a solution T1 {B1,C1}, T2 {A1,B2,C2}.

I suspect the following greedy approach works: starting with the largest group, take each group and allocate one person of that group per table, picking first tables with the most free seats.

Comment: No proof yet, that's why I wrote "suspect"; I couldn't find an obvious counter example yet, but that doesn't make it right. And "reasonable ideas" have a way to backfire in non-obvious ways with greedy algorithms...

Answer (score 1):

The following greedy approach works:

Repeat the following steps until there is no seat left:

1. Pick the largest group and the largest table
2. Match one person from the chosen group to the chosen table
3. Reduce group size and table size by 1.

Proof:

We just have to prove that after performing one step we still can reach optimal solution.

Let's call any member of the largest group a cool guy.
Suppose that there is a different optimal solution in which no cool guy sits at the largest table. Let's pick any person sitting at the largest table in this solution and call it lame guy. 
He must belong to the group of size no larger than the cool group. So there is another table at which sits a cool guy but no lame guy. We can than safely swap seats of the lame and cool guy which also results in an optimal solution.